# Entity framework returning different result than SSMS

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I've encountered quite a strange problem

I'm trying to run a stored procedure via entity framework to work out the counts of various people with a date of birth within a certain range

I'm running the following code

```
select count(*), groupId from app_people p
where p.DOB >= '2012-10-02'
and p.DOB <= '2013-10-01
group by groupId
```

The issue I'm getting is that the same stored procedure executed via ssms returns 70 whereas entity framework returns 59

I'm inserting the result of the above query into a temp table before updating an existing table with the results.

Any suggestions as to why this would be happening?

Both are being passed the same parameters.

Using the following code to execute the proc via Entity framework, the procedure has been imported from the database and is included in the datamodel.

```
DatabaseContext.TestProcedure(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that meant ssms returns 70 and EF returns 59

Comment: Post your EF code used to call the sproc.

Comment: The very first thing I would check is that they are both running against the same server and database. Usually when I have something like this happen, the application is pointed to one server and I ran it in SSMS on a differnt one. Sometimes the application is going to the worng place and sometimes (more often) it is SSMS that is looking at the wrong place by accident.

Comment: The other thing could be user rights. Perhaps the user running the proc on SSMS has the rights to see more of the records than the user that the application is using.

Comment: Definitely running against the same database, can run the proc via EF and query the resulting table that is updated via SSMS and see 59. If I execute the same proc by SSMS and do the same I can see 70.

Comment: Have you looked at the query EF generates?

Comment: Ok so I've spent a bit more time looking at this.

I've executed the same logic in code that is being called as part of the stored procedure in Linq so that I could see the result. 

If I look at this variable I get a count of 70, when looking at what is stored in the stored procedure it has returned 59. So It's definitely connected to the same database but returning different results.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permissions issue as [HLGEM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034/hlgem) pointed out. If the connection to SQL Server in code uses a different login than your SQL Server Management Studio SSMS login (e.g. windows credentials) you may see different results.

You can use the following TSQL to execute a query from another security context within SSMS. You could do this to compare the results of the same query for different users.

```
-- Execute as another user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql
EXECUTE AS USER = 'testuser';

-- TSQL with inconsistent results between code and ssms.
SELECT COUNT(*), groupId FROM app_people;
```